# Why does Map updated twice with setTimeout and React in Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, event-loop

I have following React component:

`App.tsx:`

```
function App() {
    const [countdownTimers, setCountdownTimers] = React.useState<
        Map<number, number>
    >(new Map([[1, 60]]));

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
            setCountdownTimers((prevState) => {
                console.log(prevState);
                for (const [timerKey, timer] of prevState) {
                    prevState.set(timerKey, timer - 1);
                }
                return new Map(prevState);
            });
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timeoutId);
        };
    }, []);

    return <>{countdownTimers.get(1)}</>;
};
```

`index.tsx`

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

Code above is expected to subtract `1` from all values in `Map` every second. But due to `StrictMode` it subtracts `2`. Removing `<React.StrictMode>` solves issue, but I want to understand why `StrictMode` behave this way only with `Map`

Could you please advise why it's this way?

[image: duplicated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), state updater functions are invoked twice in an attempt to detect possible bugs.

Your code here does have an arguable bug - you're *mutating* the existing state in the Map here:

```
setCountdownTimers((prevState) => {
    console.log(prevState);
    for (const [timerKey, timer] of prevState) {
        prevState.set(timerKey, timer - 1);
    }
    return new Map(prevState);
});
```

Although you create a new Map when returning, you're still calling `prevState.set` - mutating it. This means that the second time the (strict) state updater runs, the Map it sees (in `prevState` the second time) has already had its values decremented once.

Instead of mutating the existing Map, create the new Map immediately, and only change that new Map.

```js
function App() {
    const [countdownTimers, setCountdownTimers] = React.useState(new Map([[1, 60]]));

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
            setCountdownTimers((prevState) => {
                const newMap = new Map(prevState);
                console.log(JSON.stringify([...newMap.entries()]));
                for (const [timerKey, timer] of prevState) {
                    newMap.set(timerKey, timer - 1);
                }
                return newMap;
            });
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timeoutId);
        };
    }, []);

    return countdownTimers.get(1);
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of React strict mode, it does not have anything to do with the `Map` data structure. According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate    methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - **State updater functions (the first argument to setState)**
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Essentially, the callback passed to the `setCountdownTimers` setter is invoked twice, hence subtracting `2` instead of `1`. It shouldn't happen in production.